# Valet showing files under wrong Url

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet, valet

Currently running into issues on my server with links to files in my Laravel application.

I currently have a `images` folder in `storage/app/public` and I linked the `storage/app/public` folder to `public` with `php artisan storage:link`.

Now i have a `image.jpg` in the `images` folder.
On my local system while using `valet` I can see the image with the tow following links:

1. /images/image.jpg
2. /storage/images/image.jpg

On my server only the second one works (which I assume is correct as there is no `images` folder directly in the `public`-directory.

Problem is, I often run into issues when deploying as customers can't see images online (as the link is not working). This wouldn't be an issue if I could not see images local while testing the UI.

Anyone also has this issue and can lead me to some kind of solution?

Comment: "I often run into issues when deploying as customers can't see images online (as the link is not working)." can you clarify, this is difficult to understand. Do you mean that after you deploy the symlink stops working?

Comment: No the symlink works (as does the second URL) but the first one (without storage) works locally (and I think it shouldn't) but does not work on the server I deploy to.

Comment: Have you created a symlink in the past on your local machine that you've forgotten about? What happens if you run `stat public/images` from the laravel application's directory on your local machine? Valet doesn't do anything like this by default.

Comment: `stat public/images` returns "No such file or directory"

Comment: That's really strange, I cannot reproduce the issue and looking through the [Valet source code](https://github.com/laravel/valet) I can find nothing that would cause `public/images` to return files from `app/storage/public`. Can you reproduce this with a new Laravel project locally? Have you tried reinstalling Valet? There is, presumably, some configuration somewhere that you've forgotten about.

Comment: I just reinstalled valet and I got this in several projects. This also happens on two different macs and some of my colleagues got the same issues...

Comment: For clarity, just to ensure we're on exactly the same page, the issue that you and others can reproduce is: "When running a Laravel project locally with Valet, requests to `/images` are routed to `storage/app/public`, e.g: `https://example.dev/images/example.png` returns the contents of `storage/app/public/images/example.png`"?

Comment: that's exactly it.

Comment: I was wrong, I missed the functionality that does this when reviewing the source code. I've submitted an answer with the fix for you :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the [LaravelValetDriver](https://github.com/laravel/valet/blob/master/cli/drivers/LaravelValetDriver.php) has a fallback test; if the file doesn't exist in the public directory then it will check the public storage directory.

You can find that [here](https://github.com/laravel/valet/blob/master/cli/drivers/LaravelValetDriver.php#L40):

```
if ($this->isActualFile($storagePath = $sitePath.'/storage/app/public'.$storageUri)) {
    return $storagePath;
}
```

You can prevent this behaviour by [creating your own Valet Driver](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet#custom-valet-drivers) that extends the LaravelValetDriver and overrides the `isStaticFile` method, e.g:

```
class NoStorageFallbackLaravelValetDriver extends LaravelValetDriver
{

    public function isStaticFile($sitePath, $siteName, $uri)
    {
        if (file_exists($staticFilePath = $sitePath. '/public' . $uri)
       && is_file($staticFilePath)) {
            return $staticFilePath;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the public disk is straight forward and should work without problems out of the box.

The public disk uses the 'local' driver which by default uses the storage/app directory.

---

The command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

will create a symbolic link 'storage' inside your public folder that links to the non-public folder storage/app/public.

When the link is working, you can use the following command:

```
Storage::disk('local')->put('public/file.txt', 'Contents');
```

This will store file.txt to

```
storage/app/public/file.txt
```

You won't be accessing the file at storage/app/public.file.txt instead you will be accessing it using the symlink public/storage...

Therefore your saved file will publicly accessible at

```
public/storage/file.txt
```

Use the asset helper you can get the location of the file:

```
echo asset('file.txt');
```

Comment: this already works. My current problem is, that links without specifying the `storage/images` but only `images` also work locally (and I can't get why). They should not, but do. And this leads to manual UI test that succeed as images are visible (no one wants to clutter witch checking the image paths...)

Comment: Ahh, the initial post looked like it said you were having problems rendering the files on the production server... So, what happens when you do something like, 'ls -la' in the yourapp/public folder? Do you see the files there or any weird sym link locally or on the server?

Comment: 'ls -la' returns my storage symlink and the files really present there.. can not see anything for the `images`.